# What's the proper way to respond to an author-deleted question?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, deleted-questions

A user had recently asked a question about having relative paths in visual studio build events.  He came to the conclusion that it just simply wasn't possible after an answer offered by another.  That's fair.  I was about to offer a workaround but found that the author deleted the question in response.  The user now asks a different question which appears to be dependent on the last one.  No fault there IMO.

*What is the proper way for me to communicate to him that I have a workaround solution to his previous question?*

Prior to his second question, I was looking for ways to somehow communicate with him.  Since in-site private messaging will not be implemented, I thought about commenting on a random question of his but to me is not a proper way to communicate this.  I could probably leave a comment on his new question mentioning it, but it feels awkward communicating this way.  I was tempted to answer in his new question not offering a solution to the new question (as I'm not sure how I can answer properly) but just referencing his older question.  As a last resort, I was going to "ask" his question again and immediately answer with my workaround in the hopes that he would see it.

*What steps should I take?  Is there a more practical and proper way to get my message through?  What would the community suggest I do?*

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, the new question ( [Calling java file in a visual studio build event](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3662029/390278) ) and the title of the old, (Relative paths in visual studio command-line file directory).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but if you post a meta question about it and include a link to the question, 10k users can vote to undelete it. In this particular case, the question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661663/relative-command-line-access-file-directory). I voted to undelete it, so it'll also show up on the undelete list, which should help

Comment: It should be undeleted now.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this would be the place to go in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you feel that the question (and your answer) might be generally helpful, I would post it as a new question and answer it yourself.

Adding comments to an unrelated post would not be appropriate. It might even be flagged and removed automatically. Contacting a specific user this way is not implemented by design. Information passed through this system is supposed to be for the benefit of all. It's not for private one-on-one communications. If the user deleted their question, they probably consider it a closed issue, but feel free to add the information to the system yourself.

Comment: I think it'd be fine for him to leave a comment about having a workaround, then delete it later.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was considering it at first but was looking for a community supported solution.  Asking here for an undelete from the higher ups seemed the best option.