# Please review this deleted question

Tags: support, deleted-questions, review

I answered a good solid question in [objc] today with what I thought was a decent answer; the question owner later inexplicably deleted it. I think the question should be kept around.*

I'd raise a mod flag, but there's nowhere to attach it to. I found a [suggestion here on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63777/whats-the-proper-way-to-respond-to-an-author-deleted-question/63787#63787):

> I'm not sure if this is the best way, but if you post a meta question about it and include a link to the question, 10k users can vote to undelete it.

and I thought it was worth a try. Could any 10k members who have a moment to spare please give this deletion a review?

[Drawing a simple circle on the UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683492/drawing-a-simple-circle-on-the-uiimageview)

[image]

Thank you.

EDIT: Just to clarify (although it's apparent in the screenshot, thank you for that, YOU) -- I didn't think that there was a system error involving loss of upvotes or something like that. I apologize if I gave that impression. The rep issue was only the *potential* rep that I *might* have gotten from the answer; I am concerned about that, but I am also concerned about the content of the question and the answer.

**UPDATE:** As of UTC 7:26, 16 Apr 2011, the question in question has been undeleted. I don't know how or by whom. This Meta question is moot; it should perhaps be closed. Thanks to anyone who troubled him/herself to look into this, and especially Arjan.

**UPDATE to the UPDATE**: The [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5683492/revisions) link was just pointed out to me, so I can now thank Daniel DiPaolo, Gabe, and Cody Gray for their interest.

---

<sub>* I'll admit that rep for my answer is on my mind too</sub>

Comment: I'm hesitant to vote to undelete a question that was deleted by the person who wrote it.

Comment: @tvan: I don't see any reason it should have been deleted. Heck, it might have been an accident.

Comment: @tvan: I understand. I'm not 100% sure myself that it should be undeleted; I just wanted others to take a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: @tvanfosson, I can't see it, but does the answer look worthwhile? Then, if that answer would have been given some time to earn one single upvote, the new deletion rules [wouldn't even allow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471) for a deletion by the author. (That aside, I hope a moderator can peek into the history of deleted questions. This *might* be another user complaining about [being banned from asking questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions) soon...?)

Comment: Looks like its got undeleted now.

Comment: @YOU: indeed. Thanks for the screenshot, BTW.

Comment: @Josh, http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5683492/revisions - for the record

Comment: @YOU: Good to know.

Comment: It's a perfectly valid question that may be helpful to others in the future. I didn't think we even allowed users to delete their own questions if an answer with at least one upvote had been provided. That's why I undeleted the question. It's not noise, and it deserves to stick around. Too many users delete their own questions after having gotten an answer, either because they're finished with the question, or they're somehow "embarrassed" at having to ask. Both of those ignore the main purpose of this site, to provide a general resource for the community.

Comment: (@Cody, as an aside: there were no upvotes when the question asker deleted the question and its answer. Too bad the OP did not respond to [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683492/drawing-a-simple-circle-on-the-uiimageview) on the question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities, given there is reputation on an answer involved:

1. Multiple users voted for deletion, or a moderator deleted.
2. If not, then either it was deleted before January 11th, or deleted erroneously (please change this into a bug report then). The new rules [don't allow for single click deletion by the author](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471). Also, the question is licensed to the public domain. Without being able to see it, I'd say: undelete.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The "Page Not Found" explanation says "voluntarily removed by its author", so I guess it hadn't gotten any votes at the time.

Comment: But if there are votes, @Josh, would those have been applied after deletion? Still then, given the license, I'd say: undelete. (And hopefully someone can tell the user this is not nice behavior...)

Comment: Any idea how soon after asking the question was deleted? And how soon after answering, @Josh?

Comment: Frustrating, though -- the question may have been deleted immediately after <strikethrough>I answered</strikethrough> the asker read my answer, meaning no time to get any upvotes.

Comment: I don't have any clear idea. I answered maybe an hour after it was posted, checked back an hour or two later, maybe.

Comment: And you're sure about the upvotes, @Josh? Or are you expecting upvotes?

Comment: No, no; I have no idea if there were upvotes. Based on what you're saying about the deletion system, I guess that there _weren't_ any. I'm not saying there was an error. (Certainly I was _hoping_ for upvotes, because I think it was a good answer.)

Comment: (Still, @Josh, I [asked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471) Jeff Atwood if a time limitation would make sense too, to *allow* for upvoting before quickly removing.)

Comment: Thanks, Arjan, and I think that's an excellent idea (and not just in my case :).

Comment: We'll see if Jeff happens to read it. If not, we can post a feature request, if there is no such thing yet, @Josh.

Comment: I really appreciate your concern, Arjan. Thank you!